# Haskell: Am I misunderstanding how Arrows may be used?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I wrote some toy code to play with the concept of Arrows.  I wanted to see if I could write an Arrow which encoded the concept of a stateful function - giving a different value after different calls.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows#-}
module StatefulFunc where

import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow

newtype StatefulFunc a b = SF { unSF :: a -> (StatefulFunc a b, b) }

idSF :: StatefulFunc a a
idSF = SF $ \a -> (idSF, a)

dotSF :: StatefulFunc b c -> StatefulFunc a b -> StatefulFunc a c
dotSF f g = SF $ \a -> 
    let (g', b) = unSF g a
        (f', c) = unSF f b
    in (dotSF f' g', c)

instance Category StatefulFunc where
  id = idSF
  (.) = dotSF

arrSF :: (a -> b) -> StatefulFunc a b
arrSF f = ret
  where ret = SF fun
        fun a = (ret, f a)

bothSF :: StatefulFunc a b -> StatefulFunc a' b' -> StatefulFunc (a, a') (b, b')
bothSF f g = SF $ \(a,a') ->
    let (f', b) = unSF f a
        (g', b') = unSF g a'
    in (bothSF f' g', (b, b'))

splitSF :: StatefulFunc a b -> StatefulFunc a b' -> StatefulFunc a (b, b')
splitSF f g = SF $ \a ->
    let (f', b) = unSF f a
        (g', b') = unSF g a
    in (splitSF f' g', (b, b'))

instance Arrow StatefulFunc where
  arr  = arrSF
  first = flip bothSF idSF
  second = bothSF idSF
  (***) = bothSF
  (&&&) = splitSF

eitherSF :: StatefulFunc a b -> StatefulFunc a' b' -> StatefulFunc (Either a a') (Either b b')
eitherSF f g = SF $ \e -> case e of
      Left a -> let (f', b) = unSF f a in (eitherSF f' g, Left b)
      Right a' -> let (g', b') = unSF g a' in (eitherSF f g', Right b')

mergeSF :: StatefulFunc a b -> StatefulFunc a' b -> StatefulFunc (Either a a') b
mergeSF f g = SF $ \e -> case e of 
      Left a -> let (f', b) = unSF f a in (mergeSF f' g, b)
      Right a' -> let (g', b) = unSF g a' in (mergeSF f g', b)

instance ArrowChoice StatefulFunc where
  left = flip eitherSF idSF
  right = eitherSF idSF
  (+++) = eitherSF
  (|||) = mergeSF
```

So after I went through the various type class definitions (not sure whether or how ArrowZero would work for this, so I skipped it), I defined some helper functions

```
evalSF :: (StatefulFunc a b) -> a -> b
evalSF f a = snd (unSF f a)

givenState :: s -> (s -> a -> (s, b)) -> StatefulFunc a b
givenState s f = SF $ \a -> let (s', b) = f s a in (givenState s' f, b)
```

And worked out an example of use

```
count :: StatefulFunc a Integer
count = givenState 1 $ \c _ -> (c+1, c)

countExample :: StatefulFunc a Integer
countExample = proc _ -> do
                  (count', one) <- count -< ()
                  (count'', two) <- count' -< ()
                  (count''', three) <- count'' -< ()
                  returnA -< three
```

However, when I try to compile `countExample`, I get "Not in scope" errors for `count'` and `count''`, which I suppose means that I need to go back to the tutorial and read up on what can be used when.  I think what I'd really like anyway is something more like

```
countExample :: Integer
countExample =
  let (count', one) = unSF count ()
      (count'', two) = unSF count' ()
      (count''', three) = unSF count'' ()
  in three
```

But that's kind of awkward, and I was hoping for something a bit more natural.

Can anyone explain how I'm misunderstanding how Arrows work, and how they might be used?  Is there fundamental philosophy to Arrows that I'm missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Can anyone explain how I'm misunderstanding how Arrows work, and how they might be used? Is there fundamental philosophy to Arrows that I'm missing?

I get the impression that you're treating this `Arrow` like you would a `Monad`. I don't know if this counts as a "fundamental philosophy", but there's a significant difference between the two, despite how often they overlap. In a sense the key thing that defines a `Monad` is the `join` function; how to collapse a nested structure into a single layer. They're useful because of what `join` allows: you can create new monadic layers in a recursive function, alter the `Functor` structure based on its contents, and so on. But this isn't about `Monad`s, so we'll leave it at that.

The essence of an `Arrow`, on the other hand, is a **generalized version of a function**. The `Category` type class defines generalized versions of function composition and the identity function, while the `Arrow` type class defines how to lift a regular function to an `Arrow` and how to work with `Arrow`s that take multiple arguments (in the form of tuples--`Arrows` can't necessarily be curried!).

When combining `Arrow`s in a basic manner, as in your first `countExample` function, all you're really doing is something like elaborate **function composition**. Look back at your definition of `(.)`--you're taking two stateful functions and connecting them into a single stateful function, with the state change behavior handled automatically.

So, the main problem with your `countExample` is that it even *mentions* `count'` and such. That's all done behind the scenes, just like you don't need to explicitly pass the state parameter along when using `do` notation in the `State` monad.

Now, because the `proc` notation just lets you construct large composite `Arrow`s, to actually *use* your stateful function you'll need to work outside the `Arrow` syntax, just like you need `runState` or such in order to actually run a computation in the `State` monad. Your second `countExample` is along these lines, but too specialized. In the general case, your stateful function maps a *stream* of inputs to a *stream* of outputs, making it a [finite state transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer), so `runStatefulFunction` would probably take a lazy list of input values and convert them into a lazy list of output values using a right fold with `unSF` to feed each to the transducer in turn.

If you'd like to see an example, the `arrows` package [includes an `Arrow` transformer `Automaton`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/arrows/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Control-Arrow-Transformer-Automaton.html) that defines something almost identical to your `StatefulFunction`, except with an arbitrary `Arrow` in place of the plain function you've used.

---

Oh, and to briefly revisit the relationship between `Arrow`s and `Monad`s:

Plain `Arrows` are only "first-order" function-like things. As I said before, they can't always be curried, and likewise they can't always be "applied" in the same sense that the `($)` function applies functions. If you do actually want higher-order `Arrows`, the type class `ArrowApply` defines an application `Arrow`. This adds a *great deal* of power to an `Arrow` and, among other things, allows the same "collapse nested structure" feature that `Monad` provides, making it possible to define generally a `Monad` instance for any `ArrowApply` instance.

In the other direction, because `Monad`s allow combining functions that create new monadic structure, for any `Monad` `m` you can talk about a "Kleisli arrow", which is a function of type `a -> m b`. Kleisli arrows for a `Monad` can be given an `Arrow` instance in a pretty obvious way.

Other than `ArrowApply` and Kleisli arrows, there's no particularly interesting relationship between the type classes.